# Xcode 4.6 crash on Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to use Xcode but since I'm on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) it always crashes. If I try to run an app (a new project without anything) with the iOS Simulator it crashes. If I go into settings it crashes.

I've tried removing Xcode (moving to trash), reinstalling it from the Mac App Store, repairing the hard disk...but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

I can copy the log if you need it. 
Edit: log http://pastebin.com/rgsYbpQ0

Comment: Finally I had to go back to OSX Lion (10.7.5) to solve by restoring from Time Machine.

Comment: I'm facing issues too. where do you get the log ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try wiping out these two folders after uninstalling:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/

/Library/Developer/Xcode/
```